# proof Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Intermediate Value Theorem

The idea of the proof is to look for the first point at which the graph of f crosses the axis.
Let X = {x ∈ [a, b] | f (y) ≤ 0 for all y ∈ [a, x]}. Then X is non-empty since a ∈ X and X ⊆ [a, b] so it is bounded. Hence by the Completeness Axiom, X has a least upper bound α (say).
We claim that f (α) = 0.

how can be written it formal?

Comment: What did you try so far? Also, I'm sure more people would read this and help you if you use LaTeX/MathJax. For a quick guide, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I used LaTax now, thanks

Comment: Your proof seems fine. Just note that $x_n<c<y_n$ and $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ and finally  that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: how about your answer , I want to take it instead of my.

Comment: You have vandalised your own question! Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all note that the ideas in your question constitute almost 99% of the proof and handle the most difficult parts of the proof. And the remaining part of the proof is obtained by getting contradictions for assumptions $f(c) > v$ and $f(c) < v$ forcing us to conclude that $f(c) = v$. The contradiction follows from the following local property of continuous functions (it also goes by the name of *sign preserving property*):

*If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $f(a) \neq 0$ there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which $f$ maintains the same sign as that of $f(a)$.*

This is an important but easy consequence of definition of continuity and I hope you can prove this by yourself.

Now consider your question and assume that $f(c) > v$. Then using the above sign preserving property we can prove that there is a neighborhood $I$ of $c$ such that all values of $f$ in $I$ are greater than $v$. Since $x_{n} \leq c \leq y_{n}$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n} = c$$ it follows that there is a value of $n$ for which $[x_{n}, y_{n}] \subseteq I$ and since $f(y_{n}) \leq v$ gives us a contradiction (as $y_{n} \in I$ and hence $f(y_{n}) > v$).

**Update**: The question has changed and the given answer corresponds to original version where it is asked to establish intermediate value theorem via the use of the Nested interval principle.

Answer (score 4):

The quick way to do this is to use the fact that the connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are intervals.

Wlog $f(a)<f(b)$ and suppose there is a $c\in [f(a),f(b)]$ such that $x\in [a,b]\Rightarrow f(x)\neq c.$ Now, $f([a,b])$ is connected, hence an interval. Therefore, either $f([a,b])\subseteq [c,\infty )$ or $f([a,b])\subseteq (-\infty,c]. $ But either way, we get a contradiction because $f(a)\notin [c,\infty )$ and $f(b)\notin (-\infty,c ].$

Comment: Brilliant proof. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Suppose f is continuous on I=[a,b].

Suppose $ \exists k \in (f(a),f(b))$ so that $f(c) \not = k \ \forall c \in (a,b)$, we'll derive a contradiction.

Let $U$ be an open set whose boundary contains $k$, keep in mind we can restrict $U$ to be small enough so that $f$ is monotone on $U$ (Define neighbourhoods with epsilons or deltas if you wish)

If $U \cap f(I)^c \not= \emptyset $ for any $U$, then there's a set $S \subset (f(a),f(b))$ with non empty interior and $f^{-1}(S) = \emptyset$

This would imply a jump discontinuity in the function, so we can choose $U$ to be contained in $f(I)$.

Now just find a sequence $y_n \in U$ converging to $k$, this gives a sequence $x_n \in f^{-1}(U)$ converging to some $c \in bd(f^{-1}(U))$ by definition of the preimage, ($f(x_n) = y_n$)

Of course $f^{-1}(U)$ is contained in $[a,b]$ so $f$ is continuous on its closure.

Furthermore its closure is compact so the image of $cl(f^{-1}(U))$is compact, and it contains $k$.

Taking limits as $n \to \infty$ we get $y_n \to k \implies x_n \to c$ with $f(c) = k$ by Squeeze.

$c \in cl(f^{-1}(U)) \implies c \in (a,b)$, our contradiction $_{\Box}$