# prove the intermediate value theorem for the case $f(a) ≥ v ≥ f(b)$

Tags: real-analysis

We can modify the proof of the case $f(a) ≤ v ≤ f(b)$ here [proof Intermediate Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207994/turn-the-ideas-into-a-formal-proof-of-the-intermediate-value-theorem?noredirect=1#comment4542587_2207994) into a proof of the intermediate value theorem for the case $f(a) ≥ v ≥ f(b)$. However, there is a sneakier way to prove this case by applying the intermediate value theorem to the function  $g = − f$. Do this to prove the intermediate value theorem for the case $f(a) ≥ v ≥ f(b$).

could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g=-f$ is continuous and from $ f(a) ≥ v ≥ f(b)$ we get $g(a) \le -v \le g(b)$.

Your turn !

Comment: thanks , I know this way but I think it needs more proof?

Comment: Yes, complete the proof !

Comment: how can I prove it do I need to use the intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: From $g(a) \le -v \le g(b)$ you derive from  the intermediate value theorem: there is $c \in [a,b] $ such that $g(c)=-v$. It follows that $f(c)=v$. That's all !