# Intermediate Value Theorem by using nested interval property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Prove the following Intermediate Value Theorem by using nested interval property where $f(a) ≤ v ≤ f(b).$

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $v$ is any real number between $f(a)$ and $f(b).$ Then there exists a real number $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = v.$

Comment: doesn't this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2209850/72031 help you? Why did you change the earlier question and ask the same again here?

Comment: the answer was not by nested interval property

Comment: the answer was by nested interval property. The title of your original question was "turn the ideas into a formal proof..." and your question contained all the details of nested interval principle. My answer only helped to complete it by deriving the desired contradiction.

Comment: You should perhaps have a look at my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-intermediate-value-theorem.html to see many proofs of the intermediate value theorem (it also includes the use of nested interval principle).

Comment: thank you I will see your blog